# Run a word vba macro from vb script

Tags: vbscript

How can I call a word vba macro code from a VB Script:

the word vba macro code is under:

```
Sub find_replace_vik_42216()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "abc"
    .Replacement.Text = "def"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
With Selection
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
End With



Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "pqr"
    .Replacement.Text = "xyz"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
With Selection
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

could dear members create a vb script file which contains the above code, so that I call the vb script , in order to run the code.

I have wrecked my brains and troubled google, to no avail. Please help.

Thank you.

Vik

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of VBScript code which opens the document and make two replacements with given options, more compact form of the [`.Find.Execute` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193977.aspx) used:

```vb
Const wdFindContinue = 1
Const wdReplaceOne = 1

Dim objWord, objDocument

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set objDocument = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\test.docx")
With objWord
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    With .Selection
        .Collapse
        With .Find
            ' .Execute(FindText, MatchCase, MatchWholeWord, MatchWildcards, MatchSoundsLike, MatchAllWordForms, Forward, Wrap, Format, ReplaceWith, Replace, MatchKashida, MatchDiacritics, MatchAlefHamza, MatchControl)
            ' "abc" -> "def"
            .Execute "abc", False, False, False, False, False, True, wdFindContinue, False, "def", wdReplaceOne
            ' "pqr" -> "xyz"
            .Execute "pqr", False, False, False, False, False, True, wdFindContinue, False, "xyz", wdReplaceOne
        End With
    End With
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Comment: it works well, but still opens up word. My requirement is not to open word document.

Comment: @vicki, It's better you to edit your question and add your requirement. There is no such tool created yet for scripting environment that allows to modify Word documents. The only way is to use `Word.Application` ActiveX. What is the reason you don't want to run Word? May be just open Word invisibly, save and close the document after modifications?