# Compiling issues when outside vba environment

Tags: vba, ms-word, windows-scripting

I have the following code:

```
Sub vbRemoveSpacing()

    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = Documents.Open("C:/Document.docx")
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
        With tbl
            With .Range.ParagraphFormat
                .SpaceBefore = 0
                .SpaceBeforeAuto = F
                .SpaceAfter = 0
                .SpaceAfterAuto = F
            End With
            .Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=0.1, HeightRule:=wdRowHeightAtLeast
        End With
    Next

    doc.Close (True)
End Sub
```

And I want to be able to run it from a .vbs file. Copying it into a .vbs file and running it gives an error

> Line: 3
>   Char: 13
>   Error: Expected end of statement

Even removing that line of code returns a similar error later on with `.Rows.SetHeight...` having a similar issue. What's going wrong?

Comment: VBA to vbscript doesn't work like that: you have to make some changes  See: https://help.mjtnet.com/article/19-converting-office-vba-to-vbscript   and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798036/run-a-word-vba-macro-from-vb-script

Comment: Use `Dim doc` instead of `Dim doc As Document`, there is no `As` keyword in variable declaration in VBScript. BTW, where is all other variables declaration?

Comment: `Set Doc = CreateObject("Word.Document")` only late binding allowed in VBS. Or for your purposes `Set Doc = GetObject("C:\Document.docx")` (I fixed path separators). Look them up in help http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

Comment: @omegastripes, there are no other variables.

Comment: So what is tbl, if not a variable?

Comment: Isn't that declared by the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure about the issue with Rows.SetHeight, but the error on Line 3 is because [Variant is the only data type in VBScript](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_variables.htm) - there's no `As` keyword:

```
Dim doc
Set doc = ...
```

Comment: @alowflyingpig what?